# Has $\mathsf{CAT}^{\mathrm{op}}(D,C)$ categorical structure?

Tags: category-theory

In general, given a category $\mathsf{C}$, by definition $\mathsf{C}^{\mathrm{op}}(D, C) = \mathsf{C}(C, D)$ for any two objects $C$, $D$ in $\mathsf{C}$. Now let $\mathsf{C}$ be $\mathsf{CAT}$, the category of all (locally small I think) categories, and let $C$, $D$ be two categories in $\mathsf{CAT}$. Then $\mathsf{CAT}(C, D)$ has the structure of a category; my first supposition was that the bijection $\mathsf{CAT}^{\mathrm{op}}(D, C) = \mathsf{CAT}(C, D)$ extended to a (contravariant, likely)  functor. However I'm not sure that $\mathsf{CAT}^{\mathrm{op}}(D, C)$ has a categorical structure, like it happens in $\mathsf{CAT}$. Do natural transformations have a counterpart in $\mathsf{CAT}^{\mathrm{op}}$? If yes, what can be said about extending the bijection above functorially?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathrm{CAT}$ forms a [2-category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/2-category). There are therefore two possible ways we can [dualise](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/opposite+2-category) $\mathrm{CAT}$ so that the morphisms from $A \to B$ are functors from $B \to A$. One is the dual $\mathrm{CAT}^{\mathrm{op}}$, in which we reverse 1-cells but not 2-cells; and the other is the dual $\mathrm{CAT}^{\mathrm{co\ op}}$, in which we reverse 1-cells and 2-cells. In the former, a 2-cell from $f : A \to B$ to $g : A \to B$ (i.e. between functors $f, g : B \to A$) will be a natural transformation $f \Rightarrow g$; while in the latter, a 2-cell from $f$ to $g$ will be a natural transformation $g \Rightarrow f$.

For any 2-category $\mathcal K$, there is a [2-functor](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/2-functor) $\mathcal K^{\mathrm{op}} \times \mathcal K \to \mathrm{CAT}$ sending $(X, Y) \mapsto \mathcal K(X, Y)$. Both duals above are therefore (2-)functorial in both of their arguments, by substituting in either for $\mathcal K$.